# Why is the plotting-functions of package "ControlSystems" in Julia giving me a "UndefVarError: subplot not defined"?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I use Julia 0.4.3 and I have updated all packages using Pkg.update().
From the "ControlSystems" documentation, it is explicitly stated that plotting requires extra care in that the user is free to choose plotting back-end (I guess back-end means which plotting-package is used by "ControlSystems"). I have installed and like to use pyplot - hence I try the following code:

```
using ControlSystems
Plots.pyplot()
s = tf("s");
G = 1/(s+1);
stepplot(G);
```

Gives the error-message

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: subplot not defined
in stepplot at C:\folder\.julia\v0.4\ControlSystems\src\plotting.jl81
in stepplot at C:\folder\.julia\v0.4\ControlSystems\src\plotting.jl103
```

I have also tried the same code without the "Plots.pyplot()"-command.

Comment: Guessing you need to wait until this is on metadata https://github.com/JuliaControl/ControlSystems.jl/releases/tag/v0.1.4